# Не могу создать проект в gradle

Tags: gradle

[![я вообще учу курс но в курсе внизу Maven был gradle ][1]][1]

Помогите опытные пожалуйста как создать проект с папкой Test и Main
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/892vk.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не могу создать проект с gradle  для junit testa